# Can I make agents go to random attractors using process-modelling library

Tags: anylogic

I can make agents go to "n" number of attractors in an area using the pedestrian library but when I try making agents go to the attractors in a rectangular node area drawn using the process modelling library, I can only make the agents go to one of the "n" numbers of attractors I have drawn. So I want to know is there a way to do the same thing using process modelling library.

**Current blocks:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In a  moveTo block property, you should specify Attractor as your destination, and not node. And then either put exact static attractor (you should have 'n' moveTo blocki in this case) or better define some logic to determine next attractor dynamically: for example add all your attractors to collection and then specify "randomFrom(collectionName)" as a dynamic value of attractor. In a latter case 1 moveTo block will be enough but you might need to create a loop (with a help of selectOutput object) which will process movement n times.